# Pause html5 video click everywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I want to pause the video at the moment someone clicks anywhere at the website.

Herefore I try the following code without success:

```
jQuery(document).click(function($) {
      document.getElementById('videojs_id_720598392_html5_api').pause();
});
```

Does someone sees my mistake?

Comment: Have you tried putting a console.debug in the method to see if it's actually being hit?

Comment: You can't use `$` as function parameter of click event. It only allowed in `.ready()`

Comment: Your code appears to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/NpgD5/1155/

Comment: @Mohammad he's actually re-assigning the `$` variable within the scope of that handler function to be the raised click event. It's valid, but a very bad idea.

Comment: Thank you for so far. 

I get this from the console: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pause' of null(anonymous function)` 
`dispatchr.handle @ jquery.min.js:3`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
document.getElementById('videojs_id_720598392_html5_api').pause();
```

use:

```
$('#your_element_id').get(0).pause();
```

Your code should work. Check the video element id

Comment: need `.get(0)` on `$('#your_element_id').get(0).pause();`